# How to add a column to existing fact table and how to add data to existing fact table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl, business-intelligence

- Question 1: How to add a column to the existing facts table without
  recreating it?
- Question 2: How to add new data to the existing facts
  table?

I am using PostgreSQL. This is specific use case is for a Business Intelligence Implementation. My solution works but I just can't bring it together.

My web application tracks sessions/interaction between clients and advisors
which are stored in fact_sessions [table with millions of records and session_id
as primary key], this table is loaded incrementally meaning only the delta is loaded.

I want to add a new field call it "session_count" to the fact_session table
and make it persist the field with continuing to be populated in the
future loading process.

The new field is chronological in order for a specific client.
Numbering the sessions per client

I want to create a process that implements this new field. And ensures that the
new data is chronologically ordered as per the existing fact_sessions table.

```
-- Example Fact table
with fact_sessions(session_id, client_id, advisor_id, session_date) as (
    values (22045400, 2305, 10004, '2021-01-02'::date),
        (22045401, 2307, 10001, '2021-01-04'::date),
        (22045401, 2305, 10000, '2021-01-07'::date),
        (22045402, 2305, 10002, '2021-01-08'::date),
        (22045402, 2307, 10002, '2021-01-09'::date),
        (22045403, 2306, 10001, '2021-01-11'::date),
        (22045403, 2306, 10000, '2021-01-14'::date),
        (22045404, 2306, 10004, '2021-01-16'::date),
        (22045404, 2307, 10001, '2021-01-19'::date),
        (22045405, 2305, 10001, '2021-01-20'::date)
),

-- Example New Data load Each session is mutally exculsive so there is no update 
-- of record
new_sessions(session_id, client_id, advisor_id, session_date) as (
    values (22060000, 2307, 10001, '2021-01-26'::date),
        (22060001, 2305, 10002, '2021-01-28'::date),
        (22060002, 2305, 10003, '2021-01-29'::date),
        (22060003, 2307, 10003, '2021-02-01'::date),
        (22060004, 2306, 10001, '2021-02-04'::date),
        (22060005, 2308, 10001, '2021-02-04'::date)
)

-- How do I make this persistent in the fact table? How to add a column to an existing table
-- I don't want to recreate the fact table I want to add the new field to existing
-- Fact table
data_ref as (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() over(
            PARTITION BY client_id
            ORDER BY session_date
        ) AS session_count
    FROM fact_sessions
    ORDER BY client_id,
        session_date
),

-- Then i use the latest record for the clients and join it with new data 
-- and then I can push it to the existing fact table
-- I am not sure how to add this data to the existing fact table
SELECT 
    ns.session_id,
    ns.client_id,
    ns.advisor_id,
    ns.session_date,
    row_number() over(
        PARTITION BY ns.client_id
        ORDER BY ns.session_date
    ) + COALESCE(l.max_csi, 0) AS session_count 
    --, l.client_id, 
    --COALESCE(l.max_csi,0)
FROM new_sessions AS ns
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT client_id,
            max(session_count) AS max_csi
        FROM data_ref
        GROUP BY 1
    ) AS l 
    ON ns.client_id = l.client_id
```

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi I am using PostgreSQL. This is specific use case is for a Business Intelligence Implementation. My solution works but I just can't bring it together.

Comment: Are you using any ETL tool ? or you are just populating your tables using sql queries?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi I am just looking for Generic SQL implementation/Workflow.

Comment: How do you explain this record 22060001 2305 10002 2021-01-28 5 when client_id 2305 advisor_id 10002 the session count may be 1. I need  to understand the mogic behind counting the sessions

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi every interaction between a client and an
advisor is called a session.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Fact_Sessions (Session_id VARCHAR(50),Client_id INT,Expert_id INT, SessionDate DATE)
> INSERT INTO Fact_Sessions (Session_id,Client_id,Expert_id,SessionDate) VALUES 
> ('22045400',2305,450,'4/3/2021'),
> ('22045499',2305,160,'5/3/2021'),
> ('22045563',2305,150,'6/3/2021'),
> ('22045603',2305,334,'7/3/2021')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> SELECT *, 
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Client_id ORDER BY SessionDate ASC) AS [Client_Session_Index]
> FROM Fact_Sessions 
>
> )
> SELECT * FROM CTE
> ```

> ```
> Session_id | Client_id | Expert_id | SessionDate | Client_Session_Index
> :--------- | --------: | --------: | :---------- | -------------------:
> 22045400   |      2305 |       450 | 2021-04-03  |                    1
> 22045499   |      2305 |       160 | 2021-05-03  |                    2
> 22045563   |      2305 |       150 | 2021-06-03  |                    3
> 22045603   |      2305 |       334 | 2021-07-03  |                    4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d4bab3063649b6dbdb22f0b86111e00)*